# Retry not working with FaultTolerantStepBuilder

Tags: spring-batch

I am trying to build a retry into my error-prone itemreader. I have set up a small POC to test if everything is working, but I am not able to get retries running. Here is what I did:

```
@Configuration
@EnableBatchProcessing
public static class TestConfiguration {

    // other beans

    @Bean
    @Qualifier("importFullJob")
    public Job importFullJob(ItemReader itemReader) {
        TaskletStep mockStep = stepBuilderFactory.get("mockStep")
                .chunk(1)
                .faultTolerant()
                .retry(RestClientException.class)
                .retryLimit(10)
                .reader(itemReader)
                .processor(item -> "processed")
                .writer(items -> {
                })
                .build();

        return jobBuilderFactory.get("importFullJob").start(mockStep).build();
    }

    @Bean
    @JobScope
    public ItemReader itemReader() {
        return new ItemReader() {

            @Override
            public Object read() throws Exception {
                System.out.println("try read");

                throw new RestClientException("booom");
            }
        };
    }
}
```

I was expecting to get 10 calls to ItemReader.read() but instead I get only one call and this exception:

```
org.springframework.batch.core.step.skip.NonSkippableReadException: Non-skippable exception during read
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.FaultTolerantChunkProvider.read(FaultTolerantChunkProvider.java:105) ~[spring-batch-core-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.SimpleChunkProvider$1.doInIteration(SimpleChunkProvider.java:116) ~[spring-batch-core-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate.getNextResult(RepeatTemplate.java:374) ~[spring-batch-infrastructure-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate.executeInternal(RepeatTemplate.java:215) ~[spring-batch-infrastructure-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate.iterate(RepeatTemplate.java:144) ~[spring-batch-infrastructure-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.SimpleChunkProvider.provide(SimpleChunkProvider.java:110) ~[spring-batch-core-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.ChunkOrientedTasklet.execute(ChunkOrientedTasklet.java:69) ~[spring-batch-core-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep$ChunkTransactionCallback.doInTransaction(TaskletStep.java:406) ~[spring-batch-core-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep$ChunkTransactionCallback.doInTransaction(TaskletStep.java:330) ~[spring-batch-core-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionTemplate.execute(TransactionTemplate.java:133) ~[spring-tx-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep$2.doInChunkContext(TaskletStep.java:271) ~[spring-batch-core-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.scope.context.StepContextRepeatCallback.doInIteration(StepContextRepeatCallback.java:81) ~[spring-batch-core-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate.getNextResult(RepeatTemplate.java:374) ~[spring-batch-infrastructure-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate.executeInternal(RepeatTemplate.java:215) ~[spring-batch-infrastructure-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate.iterate(RepeatTemplate.java:144) ~[spring-batch-infrastructure-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep.doExecute(TaskletStep.java:257) ~[spring-batch-core-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.AbstractStep.execute(AbstractStep.java:200) [spring-batch-core-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.SimpleStepHandler.handleStep(SimpleStepHandler.java:148) [spring-batch-core-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.AbstractJob.handleStep(AbstractJob.java:392) [spring-batch-core-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.SimpleJob.doExecute(SimpleJob.java:135) [spring-batch-core-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.AbstractJob.execute(AbstractJob.java:306) [spring-batch-core-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher$1.run(SimpleJobLauncher.java:135) [spring-batch-core-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [?:1.8.0_72]
Caused by: org.springframework.web.client.RestClientException: buuuum
    at org.woezelmann.batch.starter.FullImportStarterIT$TestConfiguration$1.read(FullImportStarterIT.java:256) ~[test-classes/:?]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_72]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[?:1.8.0_72]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:1.8.0_72]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[?:1.8.0_72]
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:302) ~[spring-aop-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:190) ~[spring-aop-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157) ~[spring-aop-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.support.DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.doProceed(DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.java:133) ~[spring-aop-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.support.DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.invoke(DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.java:121) ~[spring-aop-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:208) ~[spring-aop-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy68.read(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.SimpleChunkProvider.doRead(SimpleChunkProvider.java:91) ~[spring-batch-core-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.FaultTolerantChunkProvider.read(FaultTolerantChunkProvider.java:87) ~[spring-batch-core-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
    ... 22 more
```

I have also tried

```
.retryPolicy(new AlwaysRetryPolicy())
```

but I does not work neither.

Am I doing something wrong or is this a bug?

EDIT:

I have tried

```
.faultTolerant()
.skipPolicy(new AlwaysSkipItemSkipPolicy())
```

which works as expected.

Comment: Have you tried to change the order of the called methods? chunk().reader().processor().writer().faultTolerant().retry()...build()

Comment: yes, I have tried different ordering, nothing changed. And I don't think the order should be important.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Am I doing something wrong or is this a bug?" seems like a bug. Oddly enough throwing the exception on write seems to be fine.

```
@Bean
public Job retrySample() {
    return jobBuilderFactory.get("retrySample").start(mockStep()).build();
}

@Bean
public Step mockStep() {

    return stepBuilderFactory.get("mockStep")
                .<String, String>chunk(1)
                .reader(itemReader()) 
                .writer(itemWriter())
                .faultTolerant()
                .retry(Exception.class)
                .retryLimit(10)

                .build();            

}

@Bean
@JobScope
public ItemReader<String> itemReader() {
    return new ItemReader<String>() {

        @Override
        public String read() throws Exception {
            return "dkafj";
        }
    };
}

@Bean
@JobScope
public ItemWriter<String> itemWriter() {
    return new ItemWriter<String>() {
        @Override
        public void write(List<? extends String> items) throws Exception {
            items.forEach(item -> {System.out.println("got" + item);});
            throw new Exception("booom");

        }
    };           
}
```

Logs:

```
 2016-12-08 16:04:09.618  INFO 9040 --- [           main] o.s.b.c.l.support.SimpleJobLauncher      : Job: [SimpleJob: [name=retrySample]] launched with the following parameters: [{runId=Job}]
2016-12-08 16:04:09.651  INFO 9040 --- [           main] o.s.batch.core.job.SimpleStepHandler     : Executing step: [mockStep]
gotdkafj
gotdkafj
gotdkafj
gotdkafj
gotdkafj
gotdkafj
gotdkafj
gotdkafj
gotdkafj
gotdkafj
2016-12-08 16:04:09.707 ERROR 9040 --- [           main] o.s.batch.core.step.AbstractStep         : Encountered an error executing step mockStep in job retrySample

org.springframework.retry.ExhaustedRetryException: Retry exhausted after last attempt in recovery path, but exception is not skippable.; nested exception is java.lang.Exception: booom
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.FaultTolerantChunkProcessor$5.recover(FaultTolerantChunkProcessor.java:403) ~[spring-batch-core-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
```

Here is the link to the Spring Batch [JIRA](https://jira.spring.io/browse/BATCH/?selectedTab=com.atlassian.jira.jira-projects-plugin:summary-panel)