# Spring Batch: skip after retry

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch

Let's say I have a simple tasklet configured like this:

```
<batch:tasklet>
  <batch:chunk reader="myItemReader" writer="myItemWriter" commit-interval="20" retry-limit="15" skip-limit="10">
    <batch:retryable-exception-classes>
      <batch:include class="de.codecentric.MyRetryableException" />
    </batch:retryable-exception-classes>
    <batch:skippable-exception-classes>
      <batch:include class="de.codecentric.MySkippableException" />
    </batch:skippable-exception-classes>
  </batch:chunk>
</batch:tasklet>
```

When MyRetryableException is thrown I retry 15 times, but in the end I get `org.springframework.retry.RetryException: Non-skippable exception in recoverer while processing; nested exception is` The job then terminates.

I want to **skip the item** if 15 retries didn't help instead of completely failing the job. Should I just add RetryException to the list of skippable-exception-classes?

Comment: If the exception is thrown during read, see this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40996321/retry-not-working-with-faulttolerantstepbuilder/41048833#41048833

Answer (score 0):

You can include the MyRetryableException as part of skipableexception, that will make spring batch skip the exception once retry is complete