# Spring Batch - How to retry and then skip if retry fails

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch

So I currently have a spring batch process that has a composite skip policy implemented for a few custom exception types. So the issue that I am now running into is the fact that I don't always just want to skip when I get an exception.

For some database related exceptions I would like to retry a few times and then if it still fails move on and skip the record. Unfortunately I don't see a way to do this.

I tried implementing my own RetryPolicy but the only option for canRetry is true or false (rather than false I would like to throw my skippable exception).

So am I missing something here or is this not really functionality that spring batch has?

Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40996321/retry-not-working-with-faulttolerantstepbuilder/41048833#41048833

Answer (score 1):

From a `StepBuilderFactory`, you can do that:

```java
stepBuilder.reader(reader).writer(writer).faultTolerant().retryPolicy(retryPolicy).skipPolicy(skipPolicy).
```

And yes it is working. I had the same issue and after test, I see that my items are retried following my `RetryPolicy` and then they are skipped following my `SkipPolicy`.